# Keyboard shortcut for copying filepath in MsOffice 365

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

For example, in Word2010, you can copy the document filepath pressing: `Alt`, `F`, `Tab` , `Ctrl+C`.

In Word 2013 it is `Alt`, `F`, `Tab`, `Enter`, `C`.

Anyone knows the keyboard shortcut in the Office 365?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but from Explorer.exe rather than from within O365, Alt + Context Menu will show `Copy as Path`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any keyboard shortcut for copying the document's file-path.
I believe that this would now require a VBA macro, available for documents of type
`.docm`.

This VBA macro will do it:

```
Sub DocName()
    Dim clipboard As Object
    Set clipboard = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    clipboard.SetText ActiveDocument.FullName
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

You may assign the macro to an icon on the ribbon, and also a shortcut key,
as described in the article
[Create or run a macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c).

See in the article the section "Make a macro available in all documents"
by adding it to the `Normal.dotm` template.

Answer (score 0):

You can click F12 on Word or PowerPoint to 'Save As' which gives you the file path on the top and you can copy that. Is that what you are looking for?